# Unit testing CompletableFutures, Junit, Mockito, @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, mockito, completable-future

I need help testing this CF's.

```
public class RateHandler {    
public Response firstMethod(RateRequest, Context context) {
        CompletableFuture<Response> rateRespCf = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                try {
                    return firstHandler.handle(rateRequest, context);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }, executorService);
// same here as well rateRespCf is not taking the stubbed value from the test 
//hence resulting null

         CompletableFuture<Double> avgRateCf = 
                CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> 
                                            secondHandler.handle(rateRequest, context), executorService);

//avgRateCf is coming with 0.0 value though I'm stubbing it with 1.2 from the test. 
//I looked inside the mockInterceptor in debug mode I see 1.2 under stubbed section 
//but by the time it completes executing the line it gives me 0.0


    CompletableFuture<Response> result = rateRespCf //'rateRespCf' this is NULL as well
            .thenCompose(rateResp -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->
                secondMethod(rateResp, avgRateCf), executorService));

        return result.get(); //getting NPE here when running the test
    }


    private RateResponse secondMethod(RateResponse rateResponse, CompletableFuture<Double> avgRateCf) {
        // some business logic
     for(Rate: rateResponse.getRates()) { //getting NPE at this line also when running the test since rateResponse is null
        rate.setValue(avgRateCf.get())
     }
     return rateResponse;
    }
}
```

I added my test case like this but I'm getting `NPE` by the time the control reached `result.get` not sure why result is coming as `NULL` as you can see in the test from this line `when(rateHandler.handler(getRateLookupRequest(),context)).thenReturn(rateLookupResponse);` it should return the value in `thenReturn`. In fact none of the `thenReturn` are working everything is coming as null. Please help.

//MyTest

```
    @Mock
    FirstHandler firstHandler;
    @Mock
    SecondHandler secondHandler;   
    @InjectMocks
    RateHandler rateHandler;  

    @Test
      public void testRateHandler()
          throws BusinessException, IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
       when(firstHandler.handle(rateRequest(), context)).thenReturn(rateResponse);
       when(secondHandler.handle(rateRequest(), context))).thenReturn(1.2); 
        
    when(rateHandler.handler(getRateLookupRequest(),context)).thenReturn(rateLookupResponse);
        }
```

I even tried this approach still no luck

```
    @Test
  public void testRateHandler1()
      throws BusinessException, IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    CompletableFuture<RateLookupResponse> rateLookupResponseCf = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(rateLookupResponse);
    CompletableFuture<Double> doubleCf = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(1.2);

    doReturn(rateLookupResponseCf)
        .when(firstHandler)
        .handle(getRateLookupRequest(), context);

    doReturn(doubleCf)
        .when(secondHandler)
        .handle(getRateLookupRequest(), context);

    RateLookupResponse response = rateHandler.handler(getRateLookupRequest(), context);
    assertNotNull(response);
  }
```

PS: `firstHandler.handle(rateRequest(), context)` //returns and POJO
`secondHandler.handle(rateRequest(), context)` // returns primitive `double`
`rateHandler.handle(rateRequest(), context)` //returns POJO

Comment: Have you tried `when(rateHandler.handler(any(),context)) `?

Comment: @daniu I tried that as well and still getting NPE. The problem is by the time it's executing `result.get` result is not completed and hence throwing NPE and I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: That can't be the issue - `get()` [waits if necessary for this future to complete](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#get--).